# Paramiko - How to tell which host the SSHClient is currently connected to?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a script that loops over a dozen hosts and executes several functions in each host. The functions take as a parameter the `SSHClient()` and then execute commands on it.

I could simply set some attribute on the `SSHClient()`, but before I do that, is there already a way to determine from an instance of SSHClient() which host is currently being connected to?

```
for host in hosts:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=USERNAME)
    f1(ssh)
    f2(ssh)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the ssh variable for the Client, as you've done, there is:

```
ssh.get_transport().getpeername()
```

Which will return a tuple of `('ip address', portnumber)`

Will that be enough? Looking at the source for paramiko/client.py it doesn't seem to keep a record of the value of `connect()`'s hostname parameter, it looks up the address with `socket.getaddrinfo` and then passes the result on to the transport, which is what `getpeername()` is asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am doing this to print out the human readable host name for informational purposes. I could resolve the IP to hostname, but adding an attribute to the client is easier. Yes, I saw nothing storing the hostname in client or transport, with the exception of `gss_host`, but that is only if you are using gss.

Comment: With your use case, would something like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) be useful?

Comment: Cool, I will take a look; I didn't know about Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably what you are after...

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('hostname')
hostname = stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
print(hostname)
```

**How it works:**
On any windows and linux, if you type `hostname` on any terminal, then you will get back the server name. We execute this cmd on the remote, get back the returned output and change it from byte to string format and finally take off trailing new line character.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue:

getpeername() returns an IP address, which is not very user friendly for a log message. So I wrapped it with socket.gethostbyaddr().

This returns the FQDN as a string:

```
socket.gethostbyaddr(ssh.get_transport().getpeername()[0])[0])
```

And this splits it to just the hostname itself:

```
socket.gethostbyaddr(ssh.get_transport().getpeername()[0])[0].split('.')[0])
```